# IIS Error when asp.net access file sharing

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, file-sharing

I'm getting error after I deployed my ASP website.

The function of my website is a file manager that access file in a shared network  within intranet. When I ran it in visual studio, "it works" but after I deployed it to IIS, it can't access file in sharing network.

> ### Server Error in '/dd' Application.

The specified network name is no longer available.

> Description says : An unhanded exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The specified network name
>   is no longer available.

Source Error:

```
An unhanded exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception
```

Stack Trace:

```
[IOException: The specified network name is no longer available.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +11185413
   System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit() +241
   System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) +445
   System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path) +70
   WebFiler.TableEx..ctor(Page Page, String Root) +70
   WebFiler.Filer.SetupView() +206
   WebFiler.Filer.Setup() +137
   WebFiler.Filer.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +20
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you post some code on how you did you access the file within the network?